# View java server code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, solr, server, remote-debugging

I'm trying to view the source code for a component in a web application.

On line 106, does anyone know how I can view what the server actually does (i.e. the source code executed) when it executes this query? I cannot "step into" it on IntelliJ. When I go to the declaration of .query(), it opens up the SolrClient.java class. My understanding is that the server is wrapped around the source code, and handles all requests to it. However, it is strange that even when running the server locally (via localhost:8080) and doing remote debugging (via localhost:5005) I can't view what's going on under the hood.

```
response = this.server.query(query);
```

In summary, I just want to know the code being executed by this.server.query(query). Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I think the main issue is that I'm doing "remote debugging". If this is the case, what approach should I take to view the code?  The full source code is hosted on github (append /phenotips/phenotips to the main github site).
and I have already compiled and built it on my computer.

[image: Image of IntelliJ screen]

[image: My understanding of what's going on]

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clear exactly what code you want to see.  The code on the server?  The code for the client library?  Something else?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not entirely sure about the myself, but my intuition is that it is code on the server (I can view the external libraries via Maven, and intellij would usually go to it when I step in if it were there).

Comment: I'm sorry, but if even you don't know what you're asking, then there is zero chance that we at SO can help you.

Comment: No worries, but I am confident it is code run on the server (I apologize if I came across as unsure before)

Comment: My question is a little more generalizeable: how does one inspect code that is being managed by a server framework?